# Apache OpenNLP, how to train or made new model?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

For example `en name finder` does not find some names, and I want to add new data to existing data model.
I found this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397291/training-named-entitty-in-opennlp) answer, but I do not understand

what is `en-ner-person.train` ? is it clone of `en-ner-person.bin`?

We should load existing model and add new data from file? What type of info should contain `txt file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`en-ner-person.train` is the training file and `en-ner-person.bin` is the model.

The training file consists of the training data with which you train your model.

the text file should contain the training data you want to add in proper format. Have a look at [this](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/07/writing-custom-namefinder-model-in.html?m=1#!) which explains how to train a model.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://www.nuxeo.com/blog/mining-wikipedia-with-hadoop-and-pig-for-natural-language-processing/), He use the wikipedia to have a corpora (set of documents) to train your model.

Comment: link is invalid